# How to fix 'wrong data type' error for one column when both columns are of the same data type

Tags: excel

Trying to implement this formula:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH('[2015_NCR.xlsx]NCR 2015'!$B$2:$B$700)=MONTH(C2)),--((LEN('[2015_NCR.xlsx]NCR 2015'!$B$2:$B$700)<>0)))
```

When I use column B it works. When I use Column S it gives me the error: ***A value used in this formula is of the wrong data type.***

Column B simply states dates in the format of "16-Feb-2015". Column T does exactly the same. The only difference is that dates are manually entered into column B and in column T they are put there by an IF statement.

Both columns have a 'custom' number format so I can't see why the wrong data type error would pop up for column B but not column T.

Comment: Do all the cells in column S or T (you weren't clear which one) have dates or does the formula leave some cells as ""?  The reason why I ask is because "" is not a valid date and isn't the same as a blank cell.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah some cells are "" from the formula (T) and some are "" from manual input (B)

Comment: Cells left blank are completely different from a formula that produces "" so I think I can make an answer.